# Why do I get a conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘const boost::filesystem::path’ is ambiguous error?

Tags: c++

Here are the function declarations that result in this error

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes) {
    write_optimized_model_to_disk(unoptimized_model_path, unoptimized_model_bytes, optimized_model_bytes, NULL);
}


fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                       const fs::path &optimized_path) {

        fs::path optimized_model_path = optimized_path;
        if(!optimized_model_path) {
            optimized_model_path = get_optimized_model_path(unoptimized_model_path);
        }
         ....
```

The error itself is

```
/opt/workspace/IhmActon/model_optimizer/src/model_optimizer/model_optimizer.cpp:144:111: error: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘const boost::filesystem::path’ is ambiguous
     write_optimized_model_to_disk(unoptimized_model_path, unoptimized_model_bytes, optimized_model_bytes, NULL);
```

I want the first function to call the second function with null being set as the last parameter. The second function will then do a null check against that parameter and assign it if it's null

How do I fix this error? I don't understand why I'm getting an is ambiguous error

Comment: Thou shalt not provide a null pointer as an argument to a reference parameter. It looks like you want to use a good old pointer.

Comment: If your fourth argument is optional, why not just make it default to `fs::path()` (or just `{}`) and have only one function? Note that these values are also a solution to your current problem where you've defined two functions to do the job of what I just described.

Comment: @paddy I like that solution better. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass `NULL` (aka `long int` with a value of 0, in your case) to a `const fs::path&` parameter.  An `fs::path` object cannot be constructed from a `long int` value.

Since you want your parameter to be "optional", you have a few choices:

1. Pass a temporary object to bind the reference to:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes) {
    return write_optimized_model_to_disk(unoptimized_model_path, unoptimized_model_bytes, optimized_model_bytes, fs::path() /* or simply: {} */);
}


fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const fs::path &optimized_path) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, use a single function with a default parameter value, instead of two functions:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const fs::path &optimized_path = {}) {
    ...
}
```

2. Use a pointer instead of a reference:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes) {
    return write_optimized_model_to_disk(unoptimized_model_path, unoptimized_model_bytes, optimized_model_bytes, nullptr);
}


fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const fs::path *optimized_path) {
    
    fs::path optimized_model_path;
    if (optimized_path)
         optimized_model_path = *optimized_path;
    if (!optimized_model_path) {
        optimized_model_path = get_optimized_model_path(unoptimized_model_path);
    }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, using a default parameter value:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const fs::path *optimized_path = nullptr) {
    ...
}
```

3. Use `std::optional`:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes) {
    return write_optimized_model_to_disk(unoptimized_model_path, unoptimized_model_bytes, optimized_model_bytes, std::nullopt);
}


fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::optional<fs::path> &optimized_path) {
    fs::path optimized_model_path;
    if (optimized_path)
         optimized_model_path = *optimized_path.value;
    if (!optimized_model_path) {
        optimized_model_path = get_optimized_model_path(unoptimized_model_path);
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(const fs::path &unoptimized_model_path,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &unoptimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::vector<uint8_t> &optimized_model_bytes,
                                           const std::optional<fs::path> &optimized_path = std::nullopt) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the first function to call the second function with null being set as the last parameter. The second function will then do a null check against that parameter and assign it if it's null
> How do I fix this error? I don't understand why I'm getting an is ambiguous error

When it comes to *reference* arguments, you are supposed to pass instances of the types the reference points to. `NULL` usually is just defined as zero (in case of your compiler it's apparently zero of `long int`), and it's incompatible with `const boost::filesystem::path`. You may use *pointer* arguments, which indeed can be implicitly casted from `NULL` (you better use `nullptr` in this case, though) however in general I would recommend to avoid using raw pointers and prefer smart pointers for scenarios where pointers are required.

Here is how your function may look like (omitting other arguments):

```
fs::path write_optimized_model_to_disk(...., std::unique_ptr<const fs::path> optimized_path)
```